# Disable repaint the listview Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, refresh, repaint

In Android I have a listview where they are loaded ten lines. When I rotate the device, the listview is empty and I lose all the rows inserted. How can I fix this?

Comment: you will need override to save the ListView in onSaveInstance method and resotre your object in onRestoreInstance 
take look on this:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Users>{

    public MyUsersAdapter() {
        super(SearchActivity.this,R.layout.row_friends,utenti);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if(row == null){
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_friends, parent,false);
        }

        Users current = utenti.get(position);

        CircularImageView image = (CircularImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.users_image);
        image.setImageBitmap(current.getImmagine());

        Log.i("tag", "tag: "+image.getTag());

        TextView name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.users_name);
        name.setText(current.getNome());


        TextView online = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.users_state);
        online.setText(""+current.getOnline());


        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in activity tag in your manifest..

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Mark as right if it works for you.

Comment: I also have another problem. within each row have a imageview. when load lines imposed an image downloaded from the internet. so everything is ok. But when I flow list and hide rows images disappear. how so?

Comment: I am not exactly able to understand your Question. Can you post the code for your listview adapter ..